# What track does this bias current loop through?

Tags: current, amplifier, differential, bias

Please see the edit.

A source is coupled to a diff-amplifier circuit as sown below:

[image]

The 10k R1 provides a path for base currents to return.

But Im confused about the loop taken by ib2.

For ib1 I can say it loops through A-->B-->C(GND)-->D-->E--F

Is this loop for ib1 correct?

Im confused about ib2's track

Does ib2 loop through F-->G-->C(GND)-->D-->E-->F

But this doesn't make sense because current cannot loop back to the same terminal.

I put those capital letters for nodes as A, B, C ect.

What is the correct track for ib2?

**EDIT:**

Let me ask this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQfI5h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above conceptual schematics Rb providing return path.

What are the loops for the input bias currents in terms of nodes for ib1 and ib2? I named all nodes with capital letters. An answer would be like A-->B--> ect. easy to demonstrate.

Comment: Why don't you put it in a simulator and see the voltages on the nodes then you'll get your answer and you'll be able to analyse its performance. Several simulators are free. If it's a case of not wanting to undertake the learning exercise for a sim then I'd say you are doing yourself a disservice.

Comment: I can sim in LTspice but it is not possible to track le courant particulier. I only need to see the actual ib1 and ib2. If it is possible I would be very glad if you tell me how.

Comment: I opened a new question regarding the same schematics but different question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/364065/effect-of-bias-resistor-value-on-common-mode-rejection-in-a-differential-or-inst Hope you have an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding second diagram:

path of ib2: BAT2(+)-> D -> Rb -> X/K -> B -> C -> BAT2(-);

path of ib1: BAT2(+)-> D -> Rb -> X -> A -> B -> C -> BAT2(-);

Comment: Sorry my mistake I named two different nodes nodes D. now I changed one as X please see the diagram again. Could you update your answer with the new letter X. It was my stupidity to name both D.